# hitTest based on center of UISegmentmentedControl returns UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, hittest

I'm experimenting with some code which probes a UI to see it's structure. As part of this I am doing a hitTest on a UISegmentedControl which is embedded in a UIToolbar at the bottom of the screen. I have a structure like this:

```
UIToolbar
    UISegmentedControl
        UISegment
        ...
```

I get the centre of the UISegmentedControl and hit test it like this:

```
UIView *view = // code which gets a reference to the UISegmentedControl.
frameInWindow = [view.window convertRect:view.frame fromView:view.superview];
CGPoint locationInWindow = CGPointMake(
                  frameInWindow.origin.x + 0.5 * frameInWindow.size.width,
                  frameInWindow.origin.y + 0.5 * frameInWindow.size.height);
UIView *target = [view.window hitTest:locationInWindow withEvent:nil];
```

I've been over this numerous times and I cannot see why it sets `target` to the UIToolbar instead of the UISegmentedControl. I would have expected target to be the same control. Or some UIView inside the segmented control.

Comment: did you tried to visualise that point to ensure that it points to UISegmentedControl instead of UIToolbar?

Comment: Yep I've dumped out the co-ords of the relevant frames etc and everything looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say:

> "This method ignores view objects that are hidden, that have disabled
>   user interaction, or have an alpha level less than 0.01. This method
>   does not take the view’s content into account when determining a hit.
>   Thus, a view can still be returned even if the specified point is in a
>   transparent portion of that view’s content."

Is user interaction with your segmented control enabled?

Comment: That was something I looked into. I dumped out the entire tree of the UI with the user interation value. Everything in the segmented control is enabled except for the labels and images it uses for each button. The doco on hit test says that this should not be a problem as it only uses the property as an indicator of whether to process the controls subviews.